# Sorting objects of ArrayList by their date and time

Tags: java

I have 10 objects in an `ArrayList` with Patient ID and Appointment date as instance variables. How do I sort the patients by the appointment date?

For some reason I am unable to use a `Comparator` to sort the `ArrayList`; the compiler gives an error:

> java.util.Comparator is abstract; cannot be instantiated

`Collections.sort()` does not work for `Object` when not using `Comparator`.

```java
ArrayList<Appointment> testApp = new ArrayList<>();

while (!App.isEmpty()) {
    tempA = (Appointment) App.dequeue();

    if (tempA.getPatID().equals(search)) {
        testApp.add(tempA);
    }

    tempApp.enqueue(tempA);
}

while (!tempApp.isEmpty()) {
    tempA = (Appointment) tempApp.dequeue();
    App.enqueue(tempA);
}

Collections.sort(testApp, new Comparator<Appointment>());
```

Comment: Please show us the code you’ve tried, as well as the error it produces.

Comment: The error is java.util.Comparator is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: @Zabuza, yes. Sorry. Was editing on the code before posting it.

Comment: When in your title you say `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss`, might that imply that date and time is in a *string* in the appointment? That is not recommended. Use `LocalDateTime` or another proper date and time class. From [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @Ole V.V., Yes, I did put the date as a String. This is because I wanted to make it easy for me when I pass in the data when using StringTokenizer.
But, since I now know the existence of LocalDateTime, now I know I can use LocalDateTime.parse(st.nextToken(),formater);

Comment: Note : At the moment, I am receiving an error : java.time.format.datetimeparseexception
(Trying to read the date from an input file and passing it using StringTokenizer)

Comment: We don’t usually put *solved* nor *thank you* in the title, and it is not necessary. Stack Overflow clearly marks the question as answered now that you have accepted an answer, and the answerer will be sure to take that as *thank you* too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m assuming your `Appointment` class looks something like this:

```java
class Appointment {
    private int patientId;
    private LocalDateTime appointmentDate;

    // Getters & setters
}
```

If so, you’d create a `Comparator` to sort using the [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) method:

```java
ArrayList<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList<>();

Collections.sort(appointments, Comparator.comparing(appointment -> {
    return appointment.getAppointmentDate();
}));
```

That lambda function tells the comparator how to take your object (an `Appointment`) and extract the element used to sort (the key; `appointmentDate`). It can be condensed down to a method reference if you like:

```java
Collections.sort(appointments, Comparator.comparing(Appointment::getAppointmentDate));
```

You can also call [`Collection#sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) directly on the `ArrayList`:

```java
appointments.sort(Comparator.comparing(Appointment::getAppointmentDate));
```

---

If you’re always (or usually) going to sort your `Appointment` objects by date, you might consider making `Appointment` implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) so that you can call `.sort()` without passing a `Comparator`:

```java
class Appointment implements Comparable<Appointment> {
    private int patientId;
    private LocalDateTime appointmentDate;

    // Getters & setters

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Appointment other) {
        return appointmentDate.compareTo(other.appointmentDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use your last method (Implementing Comparable),
As of now, I am trying to pass the data from an Input File (the format for the date is dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss).

Comment: @KamarulAdha Parsing a `LocalDateTime` from a `String` is likely an already-answered question on SO, so I won't go into details. To point you in the right direction, check out [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Answer (score 0):

to make your class instances be comparable with each other, your class most implements 'Comparable' interface . for example if you have a class named C1 and you want to make C1 instances be comparable, you most declare C1 in following  manner :

```
public class C1 implements Comparable<C1>{
//some codes

@Override
public int compareTo(C1 other){
// here you can compare this instance of C1 (references with this keyword) with other

}

}
```

now if you use `Collections.sort()`, your arrayList will be sort

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final Comparator<Appointment> SORT_BY_DATE_DESC = Comparator.comparing(Appointment::getDate).reversed();

public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Appointment> appointments = Collections.emptyList();
    appointments.sort(SORT_BY_DATE_DESC);
}

public static class Appointment {
    private Date date;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Date` class is poorly designed and long outdated. I recommend we don’t use it.

Comment: @OleV.V. it does not matter in this case. I prefer use `long` for date even.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate a `Comparator` directly, you need to implement the logic yourself, list this

```
    Comparator<Appointment> comp = new Comparator<>() {
        public int compare(Appointment a1, Appointment a2) {
            // Logic to compare here, see javadoc of that method
            return 0;
        }
    }

    testApp.sort(comp);
```

Using lambda expression, you can write the code like that:

```
    testApp.sort((a1, a2) -> {
        // Logic to compare here, see javadoc of that method
        return 0;
    });
```

If `Appointment` is a class you have written yourself, you can make it implement `Comparable<Appointment>`:

```
class Appointment implements Comparable<Appointment> {
        public int compareTo(Appointment a2) {
            // Logic to compare here, see javadoc of that method
            return 0;
        }
}
```

This means you can sort your list without specifying a comparator:

```
    testApp.sort(null);
```